# How do I auto tabulate the fields with based on Column A in Ghseet?

Tags: string, google-sheets

[image]

I am extracting an example from my Ghseet. I have many repeated numbers ' Fruit Serial Numbers' how do I auto tabulate that information? Do I need to use any array?

I tried to use =ArrayFormula({"Duplicate" but it didn't work im stuck.

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these formulas for the Location & the Supplier :

**Location**

```
=If(COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1,VLOOKUP(A1,A:B,2,false),"")
```

**Supplier**

```
=If(COUNTIF(A:A, A1)>1,VLOOKUP(A1,A:C,3,false),"")
```

Just drag the formulas for the entire columns.
It'll replace every known reference and supplier, but leave blank where it's unknown, then you'll just have to replace every blank.